# numpy.genfromtxt is not unpacking

Tags: python, file-io, numpy

I'm having a strange issue with the package [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). I use it to read a data file with a number of columns (available [here](http://pastebin.com/ihEW2dxS)) but these are not being unpacked even when `unpack` is set to `True`.

Here's a `MWE`:

```
import numpy as np
f_data = np.genfromtxt('file.dat', dtype=None, unpack=True)

print f_data[3]
(237, 304.172, 2017.48, 15.982, 0.005, 0.889, 0.006, -2.567, 0.004, 1.205, 0.006)
```

(I use `dtype=None` because the file can have strings scattered around)

As you can see it returns a line instead of an unpacked column.

If I use `np.loadtxt` it works as expected:

```
f_data = np.loadtxt('file.dat', unpack=True)

print f_data[3]
[ 16.335  16.311  15.674  15.982  16.439  15.903  15.313  18.35   15.643  14.081  16.578  11.477]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: add the delimiter, and don't use unpack.

Comment: @RyanG that changes nothing.

Comment: Yeap, the dtype=None is breaking it. Change it to str when loading. Then you can handle the dtype conversions later on. [Also, make sure you aren't unpacking.

Comment: Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: You said the file can have strings scattered around, where are they in your posted file?

Comment: They aren't but the file can _eventually_ have them, which is why I'm using `genfromtxt`. You can just replace any number in any line/column with any string, it's irrelevant _which_ string it is.

Comment: @Gabriel you don't have to transpose, just address by column as I'm showing below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
In [448]: i=3
     ...: d=np.genfromtxt(fname, None) #d is a recorded array (or structured array)
     ...: d['f%d'%i] #Addressing Array Columns by Name
Out[448]: array([ 16.335,  16.311,  15.674,  15.982,  16.439,  15.903])
```

see:

http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays

### EDIT:

I tested `d=np.genfromtxt('a.x', dtype=None, unpack=True)` on the following data:

```
144     a578.06 873.72  16.335  0.003 
#-------^--------
180     593.41  665.748 16.311  0.003 
147     868.769 908.472 15.674  0.003
237     asdf.172 2017.48 15.982  0.005
#-------^--------
```

with `dtype=None`, unpack indeed fails:

```
In [538]: d=np.genfromtxt('a.x', dtype=None, unpack=True)
     ...: print d[3]
     ...: print d[1]
(237, 'asdf.172', 2017.48, 15.982, 0.005)
(180, '593.41', 665.748, 16.311, 0.003)
```

while with `default dtype` or `dtype=str`, unpack works:

```
In [539]: d=np.genfromtxt('a.x',  unpack=True)
     ...: print d[3]
     ...: print d[1]
[ 16.335  16.311  15.674  15.982  16.439  15.903]
[      nan   593.41    868.769       nan  1039.71    385.864]

In [540]: d=np.genfromtxt('a.x', dtype=str, unpack=True)
     ...: print d[3]
     ...: print d[1]
['16.335' '16.311' '15.674' '15.982' '16.439' '15.903']
['a578.06' '593.41' '868.769' 'asdf.172' '1039.71' '385.864']
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I wanted but I believe that is because the question might not be completely clear. I'll mark your answer as accepted since it resolves the issue of transposing. Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel -- an array (either the matrix or the row/column) must the same dtype throughout. Keep that in mind, because if a string exists in that column, then the d['f%d'%i] will return an array of strings and not floats. I edited the file so that one of the values in column 3 was "Hi": >>> d['f%d'%i] >>> array(['16.335', '16.311', '"Hi" ', '15.982', '16.439', '15.903', '15.313',
       '18.35', '15.643', '14.081', '16.578', '11.477'], 
      dtype='|S6')

Comment: I know, that's why I said that the answer didn't do exactly what I wanted. My fault in any case since I did not make it clear this in the original question. BTW, I opened a bug about `dtype=None` breaking unpack (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4341)

Comment: Sorry for blowing up this comment section -- But @Gabriel -> I don't think the dtype=None is breaking the unpack. The issue is that when the data is loaded it is a shape of (N,). dtype=None is in place so that the data types of the columns can be inferred. To infer the dtypes, the array is setup into that odd format that you are experiencing. View the docs on genfromtxt(). unpack is used to transpose the data so that it can be returned to variables like x,y,z. Now that there's no second dimension to transpose the data into, so it remains the same. This is the default behaviour.

Comment: @Gabriel actually unpack works on my machine with your sample data(even replace some elements with nondigits), could you make it clear what do you want when a column contains a nondigit element? Making it *nan* or making the relevant column a list of strings?

Comment: No problem @RyanG. If I set `unpack=True` then I expect the items to be transposed, if they are not I call that a bug :) Perhaps you can comment what you just did at the issue I opened? @zhangxaochen it does not work in my case if `dtype=None` is set. Since that was the goal of the original question I believe it's better to not go into detail of what I'd like it to do, I'll open another question about how to do precisely that perhaps tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: @Gabriel yes `dtype=None` fails to unpack, but why do you want a `None`? Both default `dtype` and `dtype=str` works on unpacking. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
dtype=None
```

to

```
dtype=str
```

And remove unpacking, as this will transpose the data. And for good practice add delimiter :)

Comment: I used this line `np.genfromtxt('file.dat', delimiter=' ', dtype=str)` and it changed nothing, my data is still not being transposed. Have you tried this yourself? Did it work in your case?

Comment: It worked for me on a test file. And on the data from the link you provided. Can you open the file in a text editor, like wordpad, and post the first couple lines as an edit to your post. When I downloaded the file it was tab delimited, so I had to use dtype=str,delimiter="\t"

Comment: You are correct, the delimiter should be `\t`. In any case that still leaves me with lists of string and what I want is floats and strings wherever they apply, not just strings.