# create matrix from txt data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a `.txt` data file like this

```
1317    1    1.0
1318    2    1.0
1319    3    1.0
1320    4    1.0
191     5    0.25
998     5    0.25
```

The first and second columns represent the rows and columns of the matrix, respectively. The third columns represent the value of the elements. (i.e. (1317, 1) = 1.0, (1318, 2) = 1.0,...)
I want to create numpy matrix from this data, but I'm not sure how I can create it. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to read those columns into three 1-D arrays:

```
rows, cols, data = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', unpack = True)
```

- Convert to appropriate datatypes:

```
rows = rows.astype(int)
cols = cols.astype(int)
```

- Create the array of interest with the required size:

```
a = np.empty((np.max(rows)+1, np.max(cols)+1))
```

- Index and assign:

```
a[rows, cols] = data
```

---

**EDIT**: Inspired by the method of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21940465/12983399) answer, you can let `genfromtxt` handle datatype assignments, but end up with *structured arrays*, which can be handled by some fancy indexing:

```
c = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', dtype = None)           # c is a recorded array (or structured array)
rows, cols, data = c['f%d'%0], c['f%d'%1], c['f%d'%2] # Addressing Array Columns by Name
```

The you can ignore the datatype conversion and continue with the creation and indexing of your array of interest.